# Tag cleanup: CFL and CCFL

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup

Both "CFL" and "CCFL" are only used a few times. I suggest to make "CFL" a synonym of "CCFL". Technically they're not the same, but in every day use 99% of CFLs are CCFL, and CCFL is a nuch more common name anyway.

Comment: I approved your other retags but rejected the first (as did someone else) I saw on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/92745/why-doesnt-my-light-work-at-night because it wasn't clear if it was a CFL or CCFL question. I suspect it will be closed so if it is maybe just do another suggested saying you're removing the last CFL tagged question that's been closed. Then it will get deleted automatically anyway.

Comment: @PeterJ: wanna bet that it's a CCFL lamp? :)